# Dialogflow - Twitter Knowledge Base Not Matched

Tags: dialogflow-es

While trying to use knowledge base Beta feature for Frequently Used Questions, I faced the below issue:

- From Dialogflow console, the knowledge base seems to be working fine (matches with user request for every question found in the knowledge document)
- From Twitter Direct Message, the knowledge base is not being matched with the user's request and Dialogflow is returning the Fallback Intent. To note, that:

  1. Dialogflow - Twitter integration was done based on the latest release (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations/tree/master/twitter#readme)
  2. The rest of the intents are being matched normally
  3. The knowledge base in enabled (all detect intent requests should find automated responses using this knowledge base as per Google Documentation)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Since this is an issue regarding a beta feature that works well on dialogflow console but not on the dialogflow-twitter integration, I opened a Public Issue Tracker so Dialogflow Engineers investigate if this is related with a known issue: http://issuetracker.google.com/173608857